# Multiple DataContext in wpf MVVM?

Tags: wpf, mvvm

i have a window that i'd like to bind the data context from 2 different DataModels from.  i've come across this post:
[WPF binding multiple controls to different datacontexts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679933/wpf-binding-multiple-controls-to-different-datacontexts) and it's not working in my code.  i don't know if you have to set a 'new' instance of the classes to make it work, but i can't get it to show my data.  here's a sample

```
<Grid>
    <Button Command="{Binding FurnaceDataViewModel.StartButtonCommand}"/>
    <Button Command="{Binding FurnaceDataViewModel.StopButtonCommand}"/>
    <Button Command="{Binding FurnaceDataViewModel.ClearButtonCommand}"/>

    <Label Content="{Binding FurnaceDataModel.TotalTimeIdle}" />
    <Label Content="{Binding FurnaceDataModel.GallonsUsed}" />
    <Label Content="{Binding FurnaceDataModel.TotalMoney}" />
    <Label Content="{Binding FurnaceDataModel.TotalTimeRun}" />       

</Grid>
```

i have my MainWindow Class:

```
FurnaceDataContext dataContext = new FurnaceDataContext();
InitializeComponent();
DataContext = dataContext;
```

here's my DataContext class

```
class FurnaceDataContext
{
    public FurnaceDataViewModel FurnaceDataViewModel { get; set; }
    public FurnaceDataModel FurnaceDataModel { get; set; }
    public SqlDataModel SqlDataModel { get; set; }
}
```

i can't get it to display my text correctly or my button commands. any ideas?

Comment: Probably because properties of your `dataContext` object are equal to null. You should assign inner properties too, like `dataContext.FurnaceDataViewModel = something;`

Comment: Where are you creating new instance of FurnaceDataViewModel  and FurnaceDataModel ?  are you?.... You need to create it.FurnaceDataContext dataContext = new FurnaceDataContext(); datacontext.FurnaceDataViewModel = new ...(); ..so on

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to instantiate inner props....

```
    FurnaceDataContext dataContext = new FurnaceDataContext();

    dataContext.FurnaceDataViewModel  = new FurnaceDataViewModel();
    dataContext.FurnaceDataModel = new FurnaceDataModel();

    DataContext = dataContext;
```