# Strategy for binding different pieces of data to different controls in the same window

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I come from an mobile ios background and so I am not entirely sure if I can use the same strategy for pulling data from a webserver and binding it to UI elements.  In ios I can make a web call to one API and connect that data to an element and then do another web call and connect the second set of data to a different element all on the same view in a very easy way.  This does not appear to be the case with WPF which is why I feel as though I'm not using the best strategy.

Below is my code.  It grabs a list of users from the server and binds to a ListView located on the MainWindow.  When a user is selected in the ListView, I want to grab more data on the user by making another call to the server and binding that to a different control also on the MainWindow.  This is where I am lost.  Should I be switching the DataContext?  Should I be doing what the answer in this questions suggests [WPF binding multiple controls to different datacontexts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679933/wpf-binding-multiple-controls-to-different-datacontexts) ?  Or what about keeping all data in the same ObservableCollection?  What is the best way to go about this?

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```
public partial class MainWindow
{

    public MainWindow()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new GrabUserModel();

    }
    private void ListView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        Type t = ListView1.SelectedItem.GetType();
        System.Reflection.PropertyInfo[] props = t.GetProperties();
        string propertyValue = props[0].GetValue(ListView1.SelectedItem, null).ToString();
        //Get more info about selected user

    }

}
```

GrabUserModel.cs

```
public class GrabUserModel
{
       public static ObservableCollection<UserModel> _Users1 = new ObservableCollection<UserModel>();

    public ObservableCollection<UserModel> Users1
    {
        get { return _Users1; }
        set { _Users1 = value; }
    }


    public GrabUserModel()
    {
                  RunClient();
    }
    private static string _address = "http://somewebsite.com/test.php";

    private static async void RunClient()
    {

        ObservableCollection<UserModel> Users1 = new ObservableCollection<UserModel>();

        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

        var formContent = new FormUrlEncodedContent(new[]
     {
     new KeyValuePair<string, string>("user_id", "1")
     });
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(_address, formContent);
        var jsonString = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

        JObject results = JObject.Parse(jsonString);
        foreach (var result in results["Result"])
        {
            int user_id = (int)result["user_id"];
            string username = (string)result["username"];
           _Users1.Add(new UserModel { user_id = user_id, username = username });
        }
    }
}
```

MainWindow.xaml

```
<ListView x:Name="ListView1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="208" ItemsSource='{Binding Users1}' Background="#FF4B4848" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Margin="0,0,0,0" SelectionChanged="ListView1_SelectionChanged">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>  
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Height="50" Margin="0">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="{Binding user_id}" />
                <Label Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Content="{Binding username}" />
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes in your example, you can leave the two properties in your ObservableCollection<>, and work directly with them.

In MVVM, in XAML, you can define DataContext via Binding, so you can use multiples ViewModels behind your single View.

I think you should look at the MVVM pattern in first place, and look at some examples. There are lots !!!

Comment: You can, but generally shouldn't, have multiple `DataContext` in the same view. It gets *really* confusing when you do.

Answer (score 1):

Coming from the MVVM perspective, in addition to the `Users1` property, you should also have a "SelectedUser" property of type `UserModel`  Then you should bind `ListView.SelectedItem` to the `SelectedUser` property... obviously, you want to make sure that `UserModel` implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` and call the `PropertyChanged` method within the set of the `SelectedUser` property.  Also, in the set of the `SelectedUser` property, you could make a call to populate the other data that you wanted to have populated on the 'SelectedUser`.